# javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

Tags: java, base64, aes

I'm working on a project where I'm doing encryption, which picked up a key and cryptographer with AES and then step base64. problem happens at the time of decrypting back the base64 to AES and AES and return to String. Below the error and the code

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;

public class Criptografia {
    byte[] chave = "chave de 16bytes".getBytes();

    public String encriptaAES(String chaveCriptografada)
            throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        try {

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            byte[] mensagem = chaveCriptografada.getBytes();
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(chave, "AES"));
            chaveCriptografada = cipher.doFinal(mensagem).toString();



            chaveCriptografada  =Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(chaveCriptografada.getBytes("utf-8"));


        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return chaveCriptografada;

    }


    public String descriptografaAES(String chaveCriptografada) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

        byte[] base64decodedBytes = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(chaveCriptografada);

        chaveCriptografada= base64decodedBytes.toString();


         try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(this.chave, "AES"));
             byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(chaveCriptografada.getBytes("UTF-8"));
             chaveCriptografada=decrypted.toString();

        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return chaveCriptografada;


    }   

}

Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:922)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:833)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at Criptografia.descriptografaAES(Criptografia.java:47)
    at Run.main(Run.java:15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sharing you my precious Encryption class my english friend.

```
package Encriptacion;
import javax.crypto.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
public class EncriptadorAES {
    private SecretKey CLAVESECRETA=null;
    private final int AES_KEYLENGTH = 128;
    private IvParameterSpec IV=null;
    public EncriptadorAES() throws Exception{
        //generarIV();
        if(new File("initvectoraes.iv").exists()){
            this.IV=new IvParameterSpec(obtenerIV());
        }
    }
    public void setCLAVESECRETA(String clave){
        this.CLAVESECRETA=generarClaveSecreta(clave);
    }
    public void guardarClave(String clave,String ruta)throws Exception{
        try{
            byte[]bytesClave=generarClaveSecreta(clave).getEncoded();
            FileChannel canalSalida=new RandomAccessFile(new File(ruta), "rw").getChannel();
            ByteBuffer bufferSalida=ByteBuffer.wrap(bytesClave);
            canalSalida.write(bufferSalida);
            canalSalida.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            throw new Exception("No se pudo guardar la clave\n"+ex);
        }
    }
    public SecretKey cargarClave(String ruta)throws Exception{
        try{
            File archivo=new File(ruta);
            byte[]bytesClave=new byte[(int)archivo.length()];
            FileChannel canalEntrada=new RandomAccessFile(archivo, "r").getChannel();
            ByteBuffer bufferEntrada=ByteBuffer.allocate(bytesClave.length);
            canalEntrada.read(bufferEntrada);
            bufferEntrada.flip();
            bufferEntrada.get(bytesClave);
            canalEntrada.close();
            return new SecretKeySpec(bytesClave, "AES");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            throw new Exception("No se pudo cargar la clave secreta\n"+ex);
        }
    }
    public void encriptarArchivo(String ruta,SecretKey clave) throws Exception{
        File archivo=null;
        try {
            archivo=new File(ruta);
            if(archivo.isFile()&&archivo.exists()&&archivo.length()<=700248752){
                //LECTURA
                byte[] bytesArchivo=new byte[(int)archivo.length()];
                int tamañoBloque=AES_KEYLENGTH/8;
                int numBloques=((int)archivo.length()%tamañoBloque==0)?(int)archivo.length()/tamañoBloque:((int)archivo.length()/tamañoBloque)+1;
                int tamañoEncriptado=((bytesArchivo.length/tamañoBloque)+1)*tamañoBloque;
                FileChannel canalEntrada=new RandomAccessFile(archivo, "r").getChannel();
                ByteBuffer bufferEntrada=ByteBuffer.allocate((int)archivo.length());
                canalEntrada.read(bufferEntrada);
                bufferEntrada.flip();
                bufferEntrada.get(bytesArchivo);
                canalEntrada.close();
                //CIFRADO clave simétrica
                ByteBuffer bufferSalida=ByteBuffer.allocate(tamañoEncriptado);
                Cipher cifradorAES = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                cifradorAES.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, clave,this.IV);
                bufferSalida.put(cifradorAES.doFinal(bytesArchivo));
                bufferSalida.flip();
                //ESCRITURA
                if(archivo.delete()){
                    FileChannel canalSalida=new RandomAccessFile(archivo,"rw").getChannel();
                    canalSalida.write(bufferSalida);
                    canalSalida.close();
                }else throw new Exception("No se pudo borrar el archivo "+archivo.getName()+", si lo tiene abierto, ciérrelo.");
            }else{
                if(!archivo.exists())throw new Exception("El archivo "+archivo.getName()+" no existe");
                if(!archivo.isFile())throw new Exception("No puede encriptar un directorio, trate\nde comprimirlo antes para luego encriptar los archivos");
                if(archivo.length()>700248752)throw new Exception("No se puede encriptar el archivo "+archivo.getName()+" porque ha superado el tamaño máximo\nde capacidad de memoria del JVM");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            throw new Exception("Hubo un error al encriptar el archivo\n"+ archivo.getName() +"\n"+ex);
        }
    }
    public void desencriptarArchivo(String ruta,SecretKey clave)throws Exception{
        File archivoEncriptado=null;
        try{
            archivoEncriptado=new File(ruta);
            if(archivoEncriptado.exists()){
                //LECTURA
                byte[]bytesArchivoEncriptado=new byte[(int)archivoEncriptado.length()];
                int tamañoBloque=AES_KEYLENGTH/8;
                int numBloques=((int)archivoEncriptado.length()%tamañoBloque==0)?(int)archivoEncriptado.length()/tamañoBloque:((int)archivoEncriptado.length()/tamañoBloque)+1;
                FileChannel canalEntrada=new RandomAccessFile(archivoEncriptado, "r").getChannel();
                ByteBuffer bufferEntrada=ByteBuffer.allocate((int)archivoEncriptado.length());
                canalEntrada.read(bufferEntrada);
                bufferEntrada.flip();
                bufferEntrada.get(bytesArchivoEncriptado);
                canalEntrada.close();
                //DESCRIFRADO
                ByteBuffer bufferSalida=ByteBuffer.allocate((int)archivoEncriptado.length());
                if(comprobarKeys(clave)){
                    Cipher descifradorAES = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                    descifradorAES.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,clave,this.IV);
                    bufferSalida.put(descifradorAES.doFinal(bytesArchivoEncriptado));
                    bufferSalida.flip();
                }
                else{
                    System.gc();
                    throw new Exception("La clave ingresada es incorrecta");
                }
                //ESCRITURA            
                if(archivoEncriptado.delete()){
                    FileChannel canalSalida=new RandomAccessFile(ruta, "rw").getChannel();
                    canalSalida.write(bufferSalida);
                    canalSalida.close();
                }else throw new Exception("No se pudo eliminar el archivo "+archivoEncriptado.getName()+", si lo tiene abierto, ciérrelo.");
            }else{
                if(!archivoEncriptado.exists())throw new Exception("El archivo "+archivoEncriptado.getName()+" no existe");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            System.gc();
            throw new Exception("Hubo un error al desencriptar\n"+archivoEncriptado.getName()+":\n"+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }    
    public SecretKey generarClaveSecreta(String clave){
        byte[]key=rellenarBytesClave(clave);
        SecretKey claveGenerada=new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        return claveGenerada;
    }
    private byte[] rellenarBytesClave(String clave){
        byte[]key=clave.getBytes();
        while(key.length!=AES_KEYLENGTH/8){
            if(key.length<AES_KEYLENGTH/8){
                clave+="0";
                key=clave.getBytes();
            }
            if(key.length>AES_KEYLENGTH/8){
                clave=clave.substring(0,AES_KEYLENGTH/8);
                key=clave.getBytes();
            }
        }
        return key;
    }
    private boolean comprobarKeys(SecretKey clave){
        return this.CLAVESECRETA.equals(clave);
    }
    public void generarIV() throws Exception{
        try{
            byte[]VECTOR={1,6,1,2,1,9,9,7,7,9,9,1,2,1,6,1};
            FileChannel canalsalida=new RandomAccessFile(new File("initvectoraes.iv"), "rw").getChannel();
            MappedByteBuffer buffersalida=canalsalida.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 16);
            buffersalida.put(VECTOR);
            buffersalida.force();
            canalsalida.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            throw new Exception("Error al generar el Vector de Inicialización de AES\n"+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    private byte[]obtenerIV()throws Exception{
        byte[]vectorcargado=null;
        try{
            FileChannel canalentrada=new RandomAccessFile(new File("initvectoraes.iv"), "r").getChannel();
            MappedByteBuffer bufferentrada=canalentrada.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, 16);
            vectorcargado=new byte[16];
            bufferentrada.get(vectorcargado);
            bufferentrada.load();
            canalentrada.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            throw new Exception("Error al obtener el Vector de Inicialización de AES\n"+ex.getMessage());
        }
        return vectorcargado;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
This code doesn't solve the problem but I think this could help in some way

```
byte[] chave = "chave de 16bytes".getBytes();
IvParameterSpec IV = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16});
String TEST = "TEST";

    public String encriptaAES(String chaveCriptografada) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            System.out.println("MENSAJE: "+chaveCriptografada);
            byte[] mensagem = chaveCriptografada.getBytes();
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(chave, "AES"), this.IV);
            chaveCriptografada = new String(cipher.doFinal(mensagem));
            System.out.println("Mensaje encriptado: "+chaveCriptografada);

            chaveCriptografada = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(chaveCriptografada.getBytes());
            this.TEST = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(TEST.getBytes());
            System.out.println("TEST: "+TEST);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return chaveCriptografada;

    }

    public String descriptografaAES(String chaveCriptografada) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        System.out.println("Mensaje Encriptado CON BASE 64: "+chaveCriptografada);
        byte[] base64decodedBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(chaveCriptografada);
        this.DATA=new String(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(this.DATA));
        System.out.println("TEST: "+TEST);
        System.out.println("Mensaje Encriptado: "+new String(base64decodedBytes));
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(this.chave, "AES") , this.IV);
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(base64decodedBytes);
            chaveCriptografada = new String(decrypted);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return chaveCriptografada;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        AESCipher cipher = new AESCipher();
        String mensajeEncriptado = cipher.encriptaAES("mensaje");
        System.out.println("Mensaje encriptado CON BASE 64: "+mensajeEncriptado);
        System.out.println("Mensaje desencriptado: "+cipher.descriptografaAES(mensajeEncriptado));
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but still can not solve just looking at your class, my problem is the same when I return the base64.

Comment: wow I kept trying in so much ways I just got terribly stucked at this point. Notify me if you have finally resolved it.

Comment: I could look at it this example http://howtodoinjava.com/security/java-aes-encryption-example/,  hope it helps you too.

Comment: The example there uses only AES, where you don't. Is it necessary to use base64 in your case? I think base64 entangles the byte conversion in the algorithm you posted, therefore the string length received by the `descriptografaAES` function does not match with original base64 encoded and AES encrypted string(which is returned by `encriptaAES`)

Comment: Yes, exactly so I was having the problem